# How shall I save a figure which is made by 'matplotlib.pyplot' on Odoo?

Tags: odoo, matplotlib-basemap

in .py file:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

….

Pic=fields.Binary(‘Picture’)

….

x=[1,2,3,4]

y=[4,7,9,8]

plt.plot(x,y)

Now I want “Pic” to show the figure made by “plt.plot(x,y)” on .py file, how shall I?

in addtion, what if make “Pic” to show picture saved in “/home/user/pic.png” by python code?

-----------------------------update according to Trần Khải Hoàng's advice-------------------------------------------

.py codes:

```
 @api.multi
 def plotfig(self,cr):
   x=[1,2,3,4]
   y=[4,7,9,8]
   plt.plot(x,y)
   tem='/tmp/%s.png' % cr['uid']
   plt.savefig(tem)
   pic_data=open(tem,'rb').read()
   self.write({'Pic':base64.encodestring(pic_data)})
   os.remove(tem)
```

Now when user create a record and clicks button "plotfig", a figure will be shown on "Pic"; all seams ok untill now(in addition, how shall I decide the size of "Fig" by codes);

but if the user create another record and clicks button "plotfig" again, he/she will get warning:  "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop"; sometime the warning is "Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked Aborted" / "Segmentation fault" and the Odoo server will shut down automaticly.

if I click "Ctrl+c" to stop Odoo server, I will also get warning: "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop";

I don;t know how to resolve these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

1. Save the plot to file image
2. Read the file and save in Odoo binary field

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[4,7,9,8]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('/home/user/pic.png')
pic_data = open('/home/user/pic.png','rb').read()
self.write({'Pic':base64.encodestring(pic_data )})
```

Comment: thank you very much; I have test the codes and it is what I requested exactly; but I still find some little bugs which I show by updating this question.

Comment: Hi try to use tempfile to create new image file:`pic_file_name= tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.png')`

Comment: ok, thank you for your always support; These days I have resolve this problem by adding below codes: import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg'); thank you again!